# Facing trouble to insert php variable in javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to insert php variable in a javascript code but unable to get the result. Code is:

```
<?php $twitterusername = get_option_tree( 'twitter_name', '', 'true' );?>

<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://twitterforweb.com/twitterbox.js?username=$twitterusername&settings=0,1,2,248,279,ffffff,0,c4c4c4,101010,1,1,336699' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

Actually my text editor is not marking $twitterusename inside the script as valid php code. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://twitterforweb.com/twitterbox.js?username=<?php echo $twitterusername;?>settings=0,1,2,248,279,ffffff,0,c4c4c4,101010,1,1,336699' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

As it's a PHP variable, you need to echo it out with PHP, not javascript.

So you need to replace

```
$twitterusername
```

with

```
<?php echo $twitterusername; ?>
```

Even though it's inside the `<script>` tags, it's going to echo out whatever `$twitterusername` is as long as it's in `PHP` tags.

If your server supports shortcode, you could use

```
<?=$twitterusername;?>
```

making it slightly shorter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://twitterforweb.com/twitterbox.js?username=<?=$twitterusername;?>settings=0,1,2,248,279,ffffff,0,c4c4c4,101010,1,1,336699' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid php code, you need to mark it as so using `<?php echo $twitterusername; ?>`.

Your final code would look like:

```
<?php $twitterusername = get_option_tree( 'twitter_name', '', 'true' );?>

<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://twitterforweb.com/twitterbox.js?username=<?php echo $twitterusername; ?>&settings=0,1,2,248,279,ffffff,0,c4c4c4,101010,1,1,336699' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php tags (`<? ?>`) to insert variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://twitterforweb.com/twitterbox.js?username=<?=$twitterusername?>&settings=0,1,2,248,279,ffffff,0,c4c4c4,101010,1,1,336699' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are using your PHP variable outside PHP tags.